# WordPress customized permalink structure with short URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url, permalinks, short

I'm building a blog with WordPress. I'm new to WordPress, but I have decent knowledge about PHP.

I want to change the permalink structure to use bit.ly type of short URL so that it looks like this:
http://mydomain.com/wordpress/Ng4tA

It doesn't have be exactly like this, but the last part ("Ng4tA"), i.e., the short URL part, is the key.

I've googled a lot but find nothing. The closest thing I've found was a plugin named "Short URL". It does generate short URLs I desire. But instead of changing the permalinks, it only offers redirects to original permalinks.

I'm guessing that the only way to do it is to modify the code myself.

I have developed a function to generate short URL parts based on post_id (post_id_to_short_url()) and vice versa (short_url_to_post_id()). So what's left is how to use them.

How shall I do it?

Do I need to create a new Permalink Structure Tag? Do I need to do anything with rewrite and/or .htaccess? Or anything else?

If this is doable, I'd also like the short URLs to be searchable by visitors.

Thanks.